# minimization of sum of distances using elementary methods

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I want to find a solution to the following minimization problem using only elementary methods.

This is to say: high school algebra, basic inequalities, basic trigonometry and trigonometrical equations, Euclidean geometry, basic analytic geometry

**but not** any method that involves derivatives

> **problem:** Consider the points $B(4,3)$, $C(6,1)$ and $M(2,k)$. Find the $k$ so the sum
>
> $$ \lVert \vec{MB} \rVert\ + \lVert \vec{MC} \rVert  $$
>
> becomes the minimum.

*my thoughts:*

*let's use a easier notation, so:*

$$\lVert \vec{BC} \rVert\ = a $$

$$ \lVert \vec{MB} \rVert\ = b $$

$$\lVert \vec{MC} \rVert\ = c$$

*and*
$$ \phi=\angle BMC $$

*we want to find the minimum of $b+c$ or the minimum of $(b+c)^2$*

*but*

$$(b+c)^2=b^2+c^2+2bc$$

*The law of cosines for the triangle $BMC$ gives*

$$a^2=b^2+c^2- 2bc \cdot \cos\phi$$

*if we use both equations we want to find the minimum of*

$$a^2+2bc(\cos\phi+1)$$

*which implies that* $$\cos\phi = -1$$

Is this method valid?

Do you have any other approach?

Comment: Do you mean $B(4,3)$ instead of $A(4,3)$?

Comment: yes i will edit  it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be thought of as a reflection problem.  That is to say, reflect the point $A$ through the line $x=2$ (obtaining the point $\hat {A}=(0,3)$) and then draw the straight line segment connecting $\hat {A}$ to $C$.  That segment crosses the line $x=2$ at the desired point $M$.

Comment: Can you elaborate some more.Why is this the desired point?

Comment: Let $M_k=(2,k)$ be any point on the line $x=2$.  Then the pythagorean theorem tells you that $d(\hat {A},M_k)=d(A,M_k)$.  Thus I can rephrase your problem to involve $\hat {A}$ instead of $A$.  But the straight segment is the shortest path connecting $\hat {A}$ to $C$.  Should have said, this is a very old argument, usually ascribed to Heron.

Comment: Note:  I missed your edit.  Of course, where I have used $A$  I mean to refer to what you are now calling $B$.

Comment: Here is a good reference:  http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/HeronsProblem.shtml#explanation